# Why do Generators generate inconsistent voltage?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'm ultimately trying to understand the function of resistors in a circuit. The way I see it, a small increase in voltage could result in a high increase in current that would "burn out" an LED if there is no resistor to ensure that the correct amount of current reaches the LED. So what causes a Generator to generate inconsistent voltage that would call for a resistor in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not merely “a small increase:” **any** voltage operating over zero resistance drives an infinite current.

Nature abhors an inifinity, so in practice you drive things out of their predictable regimes. Without the resistors there you 
may start to notice all of the ways that your other components fail to be ideal, like your power supply’s input impedance or the resistivity in your wires. These are hard to predict and hard to control over time. Other components like inductors and capacitors can also absorb the infinities, but they have their own complications—in particular, LC-circuits are prototypical oscillators and you might have trouble building systems in a quiet, predictable state.

In fact, resistors cannot smooth out irregularities in power supply voltage: they transfer it directly to irregularities in current. If you want to smooth that out in a DC scenario, you want a “low pass filter:” you either want a capacitor in parallel with your load, so that dips in the power supply’s voltage are temporarily supplemented with the capacitor’s voltage while peaks are greedily absorbed by the capacitor first, or an inductor in series with the load, which does the same vis-a-vis the current. If you want to target a specific cutoff frequency for such a filter, resistors also become indispensable for that.

We need resistors as [voltage dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) and to take a fixed voltage difference and convert it to a predictable low current independent of the details of the wiring and the power supply. We need them to damp out oscillators that we create with inductors and capacitors. But we don't use them to make our power supplies more uniform, because they cannot store energy, they can only dissipate it.

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly observed, a small increase in a forward voltage could lead to a significant increase of an LED current and, due to non-linear IV characteristics of LED's (as other diodes), the greater the current - the more sensitive it becomes to voltage changes.

Still, it seems that you should be able to adjust the voltage of your power source to get the exact current you want.

Although it is certainly possible, it is not practical.

For instance, if you replace one LED by another (even of the same type) or the ambient temperature increases, the LED current could increase dramatically, which could lead to overheating. Moreover, the higher current will result in even higher LED temperature, further increasing the current and the probability of a failure.

So, even if the voltage of your power source does not change, the LED current could change.

Inserting a resistor in series with an LED puts a limit on the LED current, since every time the LED current increases, the voltage drop on the resistor increases accordingly, reducing the voltage across the LED. In fact, the resistor is often used to set the LED current using the following formula:

$R=\frac {(V_{batt}-V_f)} I$,

where $V_f$ is a typical forward voltage for a given LED type or color and given current level $I$.

To summarize, at a given forward voltage level, the LED current will change with temperature and will vary from device to device. In addition, LED's are susceptible to thermal runaway. Therefore, series resistors or other means of stabilizing and limiting the LED current are used in all practical LED circuits.